# How to obtain the value from a form:select jsp?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp-tags

This is part of a table in a jsp that shows users and role values...

I can not get the actual value into the url /toggleproposalrole?id=${siteUser.id}&proposal_role=${selected} when I select one of the values in the dropdown list..... just like this: ...

192.168.160.128:8080/toggleproposalrole?id=82&proposal_role=[USER,%20ORGANIZER,%20MANAGER]

The URL shows all the values from the dropdown list, not the one that has been selected.

Any hint or alternative would be appreciated.

```
<td>
<div class="form-group">
    <form:select path="proposalRoles" id="proposalRoles" name="proposalRoles">
        <form:option value="" label="Select" />
        <form:options items="${proposalRoles}" 
        value="${proposalRoles}" selected="${selected}"/>
    </form:select>
</div>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="${contextRoot}/toggleproposalrole?id=${siteUser.id}&proposal_role=${selected}">
        <button class="btn-u" type="button">Modificar</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:select path="proposalRoles" id="proposalRoles" name="proposalRoles">
        <form:option value="" label="Select" />
        <form:options items="${proposalRoles}" 
        value="${proposalRoles}" selected="${selected}"/>
```

You're passing the same data into both `items` and `value` which looks to be your list of all roles. `value` would only be used to set a specific value. Otherwise, you just want to leave it empty so that the selected value gets sent to the server. So maybe do this...

```
<form:select path="proposalRoles" id="proposalRoles" name="proposalRoles">
        <form:option value="" label="Select" />
        <form:options items="${proposalRoles}" selected="${selected}"/>
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpl, but I do not see your point in the code you have pasted... isnt it the same? Sorry

Comment: I was just pointing our your code. It is the same. I'm telling you what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: Sorry Gregg, but I do not see what do you want me to change.

Comment: Sorry Gregg, but the selected value is not appering in the a href="${contextRoot}/toggleproposalrole?id=${siteUser.id}&proposal_role=${selected} and I still do not know why. Thanks again for your help.